# I want multiple @ postconstruct methods in a class to be executed sequentially

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I hope they will be executed in the specified order, but the execution result is random,Use @order invalid,Each method is independent, temporarily unable to put it in one method

Comment: Why not just call them all sequentially yourself? For that matter, `@PostConstruct` is generally flaky and is usually better replaced with a constructor.

Comment: Please update your question to explain why you can't simply call the methods in the correct order from a single @PostConstruct method, also, include some code to illustrate what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling these methods from a single @postconstruct method.

Comment: Each method is independent, temporarily unable to put it in one method

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
public void test1(){
    System.out.println("bean A init");
}


@Bean
@DependsOn("test1")
public void test2(){
    System.out.println("test2");
}


@Bean
@DependsOn("test2")
public void test3(){
    System.out.println("test3");
}
```

You can use this scenario to control the loading order

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void method1() {
        System.out.println("method 1");
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("method 2");
    }

    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("method 3");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        method1();
        method2();
        method3();
    }
```

result:

```
method 1
method 2
method 3
```